# CakePHP combobox change font

Tags: cakephp, combobox

I am using a combobox in my assignment:

```
echo $this->form->input('Var1', array('type'=>'select','options'=>array('a','b','c')))
```

but the control appears to be smaller than the other controls on the page, as i have changed their layouts. how can I use CSS to change font family and size of my text inside the combobox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $this->form->input('Var1', array('type'=>'select' 'class' => 'myClass','options'=>array('a','b','c')))
```

And define `.myClass` in the css file

Answer (score 0):

You can specify inline style in combobox in array using style property as

```
echo $this->form->input('Var1', array('type'=>'select','options'=>array('a','b','c'),'style'=>'font-size:10px;font-family:"Times New Roman",Georgia,Serif;'));
```

Thanks